# Imagick: draw the html output

Tags: php, imagick

I want to place the html elements on my png what's created with Imagick.

My code so far:

```
$out = "<table><tr><td>There will be data</td></tr></table>";

$draw = new \ImagickDraw();

$draw->setStrokeOpacity(1);
$draw->setStrokeColor("rgb(255,255,255)");
$draw->setFillColor('rgb(200, 200, 200)');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(2);
$draw->setFont("/var/www/myapp/public/fonts/calibri.ttf");

foreach ($sizes as $size) {
    $draw->setFontSize($size);
    $draw->annotation(50, (24 * 24 / 16), $out);
}

$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->newImage(500, 500, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
$imagick->setImageFormat("png");
$imagick->drawImage($draw);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

But it renders the  `$out` as a string and not as a table.
How to render it as a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagick isn't a HTML renderer.

If you want a screenshot of a page I'd strongly recommend using Chrome in headless mode to take screenshots with some similar to:

```
use Behat\Mink\Mink;
use Behat\Mink\Session;
use DMore\ChromeDriver\ChromeDriver;


function takeScreenshot($newsletterUrl, $newsletterFilename)
{
    $chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(CHROME_URI, null, $newsletterUrl);

    $mink = new Mink([
        'browser' => new Session($chromeDriver)
    ]);

    $mink->setDefaultSessionName('browser');

    $mink->getSession()->visit($newsletterUrl);
    if ($mink->getSession()->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
        throw new \Exception("something went wrong generating news letter. Check [$newsletterUrl] is working");
    }

    /** @var ChromeDriver $driver */
    $driver = $mink->getSession()->getDriver();

    @mkdir(dirname($newsletterFilename), 0755, true);
    $driver->captureScreenshot($newsletterFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, you'd have to check the function source code but it seems to only take a string as argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.annotation.php
https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagickdraw_class.c